# Mi Shebeirach for one that is ill - if you do not know the mother's name

Tags: tefilla, names, choleh-sick

Can one make a Mi Shebeirach for an ill person if they do not know the mother's name?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2088/759

Comment: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/english-names-for-misheberach-for-cholimis-it-permitted take a look at "apushatayid"'s comment.

Comment: Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26095/1569

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they know the father's name they can say that instead (Yabia Omer 2:11).

If they do not know the father's name either, the Nishmas Avraham (vol. 4 42:13) writes in the name of Rabbi Elyashuv that they should say "bas Avraham" - see there at length.

I have personally heard "bas Sarah" being used rather than "bas Avraham".

Comment: This only works if they are Jewish.

Comment: Does the Nishmas Avraham say we should say "ploni(t) ben/bas bas Avraham", to mention ploni(t)'s mother without knowing her name, or just "ploni(t) ben/bas Avraham"?

Comment: Rav Soloveitchik in Divrei HaRav holds that l'chatchalia that one should use the father's name.

Comment: Why is this such a big deal? HaShem knows who it is. Just say the full name?

Answer (score 3):

If they do not know the persons mothers name or fathers name the Orchos Rabbeinu 1:218 brings from the Chazon Ish that one can say the persons first and last name.

Text:

[image]