# Is there a need to to know the deceased's name when studying in his merit?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, death, zechut-merit

I have been asked many times by friends to study (usually *Mishanyos*) as a  merit for their recently deceased relative. In most such occasions, I was given the deceased's name, in order to have them in mind when studying.

Is there such a requirement, that one should have the deceased's name in mind when studying as a merit for them?

Comment: similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43447/170

Answer (score -1):

We can learn from the Pasuk that Moses asked G-d to cure Miriam without uttering her name Gemora Brachos 34a (Num 12,13):

> א"ר יעקב אמר רב חסדא כל המבקש רחמים על חבירו אין צריך להזכיר שמו שנאמר "אל נא רפא נא לה" ולא קמדכר שמה דמרים ("Please G-d heal HER")

that one does not have to utter the name of the person. It holds for prayers as well as learning in memory, or any other merit.

Moreover, one does not have to *know* the exact name to benefit on his name, also one can be referred to indirectly, like "Yosi's Grandpa" or "Reb Yechezkel something".

Comment: But that Pasuk is where the person is standing in front of you. What about when they aren't?

Comment: @DoubleAA It means G-d knows your intention.

Comment: What means that? Was that ever in dispute? God is omniscient after all

Comment: Besides what @DoubleAA said, Miriam wasn't dead. I've no reason to think the cases are different, but evidence that they're not would be nice.

Comment: @msh210 she had Tzaraas and the Passukcalls her "dead so i guess it is a good example. and doubleaas coment about G-ds omnipresence should be on the question not on the answer