# If we don't and can't know someone's full hebrew name when davening for them

Tags: halacha, tefilla, names

It recently happened to me that I really wanted to daven for someone but I only knew their name and not their father or mothers name.

In general, how do we daven for someone whose hebrew name we cannot find out? Should we say "Ben Avraham/Bat Sarah"?

What about contexts of giving them zechus, like "l'iluy Nishmas..."

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited to rephrase the question to make it more on topic. Please roll back if unhappy by clicking _edited X mins ago_ above my avatar, and then _roll back_

Comment: I sometimes use the person's first and last names. I figure Hashem can look up who I men.

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2017/02/03/dont-know-mothers-hebrew-name/

Comment: Related and the two answers with sources might make it a duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26096/mi-shebeirach-for-one-that-is-ill-if-you-do-not-know-the-mothers-name

Comment: I have heard people say Mishabeirachs for the sick using a person legal first and last name if that's all that is known at the moment.