# Saying Tehilim for pets

Tags: animals

It's common in Judaism to say prayers for those going through dangerous situations such as traveling or medical surgeries. May one pray for a pet having in these situations? Are there any halakhic sources that discuss the propriety of such prayers?

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26088/759

Comment: There is a famous story where Rav Shach said Tehillim with someone for his dog.

Comment: @N.T. The story in my link about rav shach would seem to indicate otherwise (or more generally, would seem to indicate no one should trust any of the stories about this since there has clearly been telephone/corruption)

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the difference is between a mishebeirach in shul (which is ridiculous) and just saying tehillim.

Comment: @N.T. No, the story was clearly not about in a shul. It says he was sitting there and opened up a siddur to misheberach. (Anyway you haven't explained why shul is more ridiculous than not shul.)